# PIC32 VUSB3V3 must be externally powered?

Tags: pic, gpio, pins

I use a [PIC32](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/PIC32MM0256GPM064-Family-Data-Sheet-DS60001387D.pdf) and I want to use RB11. That's a USB pin but can be used as GPIO.

The datasheet specifies in 18.4 page 180:

> For non-USB operation with RB11 and/or RB10 as GPIOs, the USB module must be disabled and power applied to VUSB3V3 via VDD.

But that seems powered by external VDD? Or PIC32 do it in intern?

I think it's need external but that just to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But that seems powered by external VDD ? Or PIC32 do it in intern ?
>
> I think it's need external but that just to be sure.

Your assumption is correct: if you're using RB11 and/or RB10 as GPIO, you have to connect the same (external) voltage to VUSB3V3 as applied to VDD (2.0V ... 3.6V).